# How to name a Gender property of type Gender in C# according to naming conventions?

Tags: c#, enums, naming-conventions

I have a `Gender` enum:

```
public enum Gender
{
    Male,
    Female,
    Other,
    Unknown
}
```

I have also a `Gender` property inside `Person` class:

```
public Gender Gender { get; set; }
```

But I get an error:

> The type 'Person' already contains a definition for 'Gender'

Putting the enum outside the class does solve the problem, but I want it inside. I did not find a solution for that specific problem in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x252001(v=vs.71).aspx).Is there any naming convention that solves that sort of problem?

**Note:** I am not asking for an *opinion*, I am asking if there is a well known naming convention for such situation.

Comment: How does your `Person` class look like?

Comment: The opinion-free answer to your question is: No.

Comment: @Ian - That is just an example... I ask about the general Idea.

Comment: @StefanSteinegger - Thanks. Why now put it in an answer? :)

Comment: @Sipo: Seemed to be too trivial to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no "naming convention" that can fix your desire to have two members of a single type share the same name. From section 10.3 of the C# Language Specification, Class Members:

> • The name of a constant, field, *property*, event, or *type* must differ from the names of all other members declared in the same class.
>
> • The name of a method must differ from the names of all other non-methods declared in the same class. In addition, the signature (§3.6) of a method must differ from the signatures of all other methods declared in the same class,

(*my emphasis*)

So, you have to choose to use different names, or go with your apparently already discarded option of placing the enum outside of the `Person` class. Or, if you really do want to encapsulate it, perhaps encapsulate it further:

```
class Person {
   class Enums {
      enum Gender {
         ...
      }
      ...
   }
   Enums.Gender Gender {get;set;}
   ...
}
```

Though I think it's uglier.

Comment: Definitely ugly to add a class (which probably should be `static`) as an inner namespace. I would always go with making the enum a non-member: as part of the public interface it should (IMHO) in a similar scope. Inner types are for helpers and implementation details.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "well known naming convention" for these cases. Such ambiguous naming is better handled by defining the type outside the type using it (as indicated by the error message)

If the type is explicitly part of the API surface of a type it seems odd to define the enum as a member.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please demonstrate how the second solution will work?

Comment: @Sipo `public namespace.Person.Gender Gender { get; set; }`

Comment: "Fully qualifying the type name when defining the property." - I don't think that's going to work. The only time you can have multiple members of a type with the same name are when they're all method names and appropriately differentiated by their signatures.

Comment: @Sipo Fixed, of course that won't work (I blame lack of caffeine), the amhbigity is between the two names.

Answer (score 1):

As it was already said there is no naming convention for such cases. But as far as I remember C# guidelines discourage you from using inner type definitions when inner-defined class should be often accessed from outside. 
I would say that it is better to define `Gender` `Enum` in the same namespace Person is defined since Gender is public property of Person.